# Passing value to nested JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, variables

I try to pass a variable to nested JSON in Python script.

Script as below,

```
import requests, request

group = request.form['grp']
zon = request.form['zone']

load = { "extra_vars": {
                 "g_name": "' +str(group)+ '",
                 "z_name": "' +str(zon)+ '"
                 }
       }

----
--
-
```

However when i post the value to the API, it seem i post word '+str(group)+' and '+str(zon)+' instead the actual value that assign under declared variable.

Since i'm very new in Python programming, does passing value to nested JSON is allow in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
group = request.form['grp']
zon = request.form['zone']

load = { "extra_vars": {
                 "g_name": f"{group}",
                 "z_name": f"{zon}"
                 }
       }
```

Comment: Indeed.. this is the great answer!!.. thank you so much

Comment: If you don't need to enclose `group` around a quote, then it's actually even easier to just use: `"g_name": str(group)` or `"g_name": quote` if `quote` is a string. No need for an f-string

Answer (score 2):

You can pass variables into a string using f-strings and brackets around your variable (note `{group}`):

```
>>> group = "my_group"
>>> {"g_name": f"'{group}'"}
{'g_name': "'my_group'"}
```

Or doing simple string concatenation also, which is what you almost done in your code (but just did not properly close the `'` character using `"'"`:

```
>>> "'" + str(group) + "'"
"'my_group'"
```

All in all here's your code adapted:

```
load = { "extra_vars": {
                 "g_name": f"'{group}'",
                 "z_name": f"'{zon}'"
                 }
       }
```